# Alternative way to make class immutable

Tags: java, immutability

I was reading Effective java Third edition. The topic is

> Item 17 : Minimize mutabitity

In this topic Immutable Objects are discussed and also alternative way to not to make class final but still it will be immutable.

Here is what is written in the topic:

> Recall that to guarantee immutability, a class must not permit itself to be sub classed. This can be done by making the class final, but there is another, more flexible alternative. private or package-private and add public static factories in place of public constructor.

I can agree on making a constructor private it will make the class unable to be sub classed. But class with package private constructor can be sub classed with in the package. So will the class still be immutable with package private constructor?

Edit 1 :

The class with package private constructor is still immutable for class outside the package. But is this approach helpful?

Comment: It's not guaranteed to be, no. A mutable subclass can be created in the same package.

Comment: the package maintainer may decide that that is a good enough enforcement of immutability if they are primarily concerned about users of the package

Answer (score 1):

```
public class BaseClass {
   private final String arg1;
   private final String arg2;

   public BaseClass(final String arg1, final String arg2) {
      this.arg1 = arg1;
      this.arg2 = arg2;
   }

   public String getArg1() { return arg1; }
   public String getArg2() { return arg2; }
}
```

Subclassing this class is possible, but values for `arg1` and `arg2` must always be provided, and cannot be changed. Obviously by subclassing it you can override the two `getter` methods.

My approach to avoid possible mistakes by me and co-workers is programming to `interface`(s).

```
public interface BaseInterface {
   String arg1();
   String arg2();
}
```

Using this interface all-around the codebase will ensure a reduced amount of errors, as the internal state might be changed only at creation point. Once the object escape the creation point, it can no more be changed (well it can, but you have to manually downcast it, and that is easy to spot).

---

Another strategy to avoid subclassing (and possibly mutability) is using annotation processors. That will enforce your rule at compile time.

Comment: +1 for not parentizing on the other hand: immutable for me is somehow connected with putting something in a container and signaling users that retrieve that something: "stop, don't change this thing unless you know exactly what you are doing." I think you missing that case and only explain subclassing.

Comment: "You can maintain a class immutable and allow subclassing at the same time." Not if you want to keep the features of immutability that most users would find most useful. If I read that a class is immutable, I generally expect to be able to assume that no aspect of its state will change. I can cache it for as long as I like, and it will be fine. If a mutable subclass is created, state can be changed under my code's feet - even if it's an aspect of the class that *I* never use, if I pass references to the object around expecting it to be immutable, that can cause issues.

Comment: @JonSkeet you're right. I specified the behavior (but not the data) can be changed when subclassed. That's why I also wrote "program to interfaces", so to reduce the amount of errors over time. If the code is not yours (maybe from another library) the annotation processor idea isn't bad, to enforce a specific rule.

Comment: If you're not even making the `getArg1()` methods final, then it's not even immutable *with respect to those methods*. That's not what I'd view as immutable, and it definitely doesn't retain many of the benefits of immutability. Programming to interfaces is all well and good, but that's another case where you really can't *guarantee* immutability - whereas often that's a very useful thing to be able to do. The question is about immutability - you're suggesting options which *don't* guarantee immutability.

Comment: @JonSkeet sure! Well than I'll have to remove the word "immutable" from the answer, as maybe I misused it.

Comment: But the whole *question* is about immutability - so if you're not talking about whether or not subclasses can guarantee immutability, I don't think it'll really be an answer to the question. (I suppose it could answer the "is this approach helpful?" actual question when viewed in a very narrow way, but that's not the way I interpret the question at least. We'll see what the OP makes of it.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I think the answer still provide interesting suggestions, don't you think? Anyway, I understand I haven't really touched the "immutable" point. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: This idea has crossed my head once upon a time but I immediately scrapped it. Anyone can extend BaseInterface and a random String with some randomness utiltiy. Even if your co-workers don't make that sort of mistakes now, you have no knowledge of your future co-workers and what they would think. 

There are things where 100% and 99% makes a huge difference and immutability is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Having package-private constructor does not guarantee 100% immutability, as was already mentioned in the comment:

> A mutable subclass can be created in the same package

Developing a `jar` library you may conclude some agreements within the team and the package maintainers, what of couse doesn't not enforce this programmatically, but still is somehow under the control of the product developers.

And what about others? One can create classes outside of you library but in the same package and in multiple locations in the classpath.

If you have such cases and concerned with questions like that, [Package Sealing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/sealman.html) comes into play.

> Packages within JAR files can be optionally sealed, which means that
>   all classes defined in that package must be archived in the same JAR
>   file. You might want to seal a package, for example, to ensure version
>   consistency among the classes in your software.
>
> If you want to guarantee that all classes in a package come from the
>   same code source, use JAR sealing. A sealed JAR specifies that all
>   packages defined by that JAR are sealed unless overridden on a
>   per-package basis.

Let's say that your `jar` libarary has a class `com.example.Factory` with `protected/package-private` members and the package `com.example` is sealed. An attempt creating a class `com.example.Accessor` that tries to access those members should fail.

That's how you can ensure that `package-private` members are accessed by the limited (and potentially trusted) group of members.

Returning to the main question:

> So will the class still be immutable with package private constructor?

With strong agreements between maintainers, careful code review and package sealing it can become kind of immutable.